# Minimize htop thread window?

Tags: htop

I'm on a system with 48 threads and the view for usage is taking up 4/5 of the vertical screen space. Is there a way to toggle the CPU usage window to just view the active PIDs?

Comment: You can customize it, as recommended below: deleting the CPU entry may or may not be the best option for you, IDK. but I'd suggest looking at the `Header layout` and `Meters` options in Setup... you should be able to condense the cpu threads horizontally, into 4 columns, select which meters you want and also adjust the layout ratio... This should allow you to maximize vertical space for processes/threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t toggle the top part of the screen in its entirety, but you can customize it. Press <kbd>S</kbd> to open the setup screen, then the right arrow to move to the column with the CPU entry, and <kbd>Del</kbd> to remove it. <kbd>Esc</kbd> will return to the main view.

Other variants are possible, for example the “CPU average” meter shows the average CPU use across all CPUs on a single line:

[image: htop top section showing CPU average on a single line]

Whichever setup you end up with will be stored in `htop`’s configuration file, so subsequent invocations will start as you left it.

Comment: Ah ok great, I'll do this and then use sysmon to monitor individual thread usage.

Comment: Actually there is an option to have "all cpus in 8 separate columns" which works very well!

Comment: Yes, I didn’t want to list all the options but there are quite a few different settings — how well they work depends on the number of CPUs and the size of your terminal window.